# How to send photos on telegram with python

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to send a photo that I have on my computer to my telegram bot chat when I issue the command /screen. However, I don't seem to make it work, what am I missing?

This is the file I am working with, sorry its a bit long, but I wanted to show everything since maybe I am missing something somewhere. Look from the line ###### HERE I WANNA TRY TO SEND THE PHOTO ###### so you can see where I am defining the send_photo part.

```
import os
import bot
import schedule
import random
from time import sleep
import logging
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackQueryHandler

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Define a few command handlers. These usually take the two arguments update and
# context. Error handlers also receive the raised TelegramError object in error.
def start(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Hi!')

###### HERE I WANNA TRY TO SEND THE PHOTO ######
###### HERE I WANNA TRY TO SEND THE PHOTO ######
def screen(update, context):
    """Taking a screenshot when command /screen is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Taking screenshot ...')
    os.system("adb exec-out screencap -p > /Users/????/Desktop/AndroBot/screen.png")
    update.message.reply_text('Screenshot taken!')
    #HEREEEEE
    update.message.send_photo(?????)

def main():
    """Start the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    # Make sure to set use_context=True to use the new context based callbacks
    # Post version 12 this will no longer be necessary
    updater = Updater("TOKEN", use_context=True)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("screen", screen))

    # on noncommand i.e message - echo the message on Telegram
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, echo))

    # log all errors
    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I hope someone can help me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [documentation](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_photo):

> send_photo(chat_id, photo, caption=None, disable_notification=False, reply_to_message_id=None, reply_markup=None, timeout=20, parse_mode=None, **kwargs)

so your code would be something like:

```
filename = "/Users/????/Desktop/AndroBot/screen.png"
os.system("adb exec-out screencap -p > "+filename)
update.message.bot.send_photo(update.message.chat.id,open(filename,'rb'))
```